# ¿qué debo hacer si tengo problemas para abrir mi android-studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

me aparece este error antes de abrir mi android-studio, anteriormente no me ha sucedido y no se como resolverlo
[image: cuando trato de abrir la aplicación me resuelve este problema, lo desinstalo y me vuelve a suceder lo mismo he visto varios comentarios donde dice que solo es reiniciar pero no me funciona, tambien borré el cache y no ha funcionado]

Comment: ¿Te paso después de una actualización?, si aun no lo has resuelto y tienes tiempo podrías reinstalar android studio.

Comment: ya lo he hecho varias veces y no funciona

Answer (score 0):

Esto es un problema bastante más común de lo que parece con Android Studio, ya que se trata de un problema con los plugins.

Para solucionarlo, tienes que ir a la carpeta:

```
C:\Usuarios\"TuUsuario"\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins
```

Con Android Studio cerrado, copia todo el contenido de la carpeta "plugins" y guárdalo en otra carpeta distinta (por ejemplo, plugins2). Entonces, elimina todo el contenido de la carpeta "plugins" (que quede vacía) y reinicia Android Studio.

Si funciona, entonces es que hay un plugin que da problemas con la versión de Android Studio. Para saber que plugin es, puedes ir copiando los plugins que tenías en la carpeta "plugins2" (la copia de seguridad que has hecho) a la carpeta "plugins" y reiniciar Android Studio. Cuando de el error, ya sabrás que plugin es.

Comment: intentaré esto y te cuento como me va, gracias

Comment: me funciono tu respuesta mil gracias

Comment: Me alegro, muchísimas gracias por el feedback